# SQL Partition by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, window-functions

I am using ROW_NUMBER function in sql within a Partition of a result set where I want only the first row in each partition. Here is the query :

```
Select A, B, C, ROW_NUM
FROM
(SELECT A,B,C, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY C DESC) AS R0W_NUM
FROM TABLE 
)X
WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
```

It yields the desired results.

But instead of this, now I am using the FIRST_VALUE function as follows :

```
SELECT A,B,C, FIRST_VALUE(C) OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY C DESC) AS ROW_NUM
FROM TABLE
```

But the above query gives me duplicate values as well. Can anyone guide me on how do I get rid of the duplicates ? I tried using DISTINCT, does not help.

Comment: You could replace all of your `A,B,C` with `FIRST_VALUE(<letter>)` and repeated `OVER()` clauses to get the same result set, but why would you? What's the actual motiviation here if `ROW_NUMBER()` is already doing the correct job? Or if it's not doing the correct job, what are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Please be sure to tag SQL questions with the proper dialect (`tsql`, I believe?) so that people who are expert in that dialect can help (as there are significant differences between SQL dialects).

Comment: What about using `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: @Amadan: what makes you think that is T-SQL? The example show is in fact standard ANSI SQL. But I agree the question should be tagged with the relevant DBMS

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I admit it was a blind guess.

Comment: if distinct is not working , please share sample data to help..

Answer (score 0):

Using FIRST_VALUE on C will not get rid of duplicates of A.

If you want to get rid of duplicates of A you could use one of the following querys, depending on the role of B.

If B is considered part of the partition, similar to A

```
Select A, B, MAX(C)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY A, B
```

If B contains a value that can be aggregated (min, max, sum...) similar to C

```
Select A, MAX(B), MAX(C)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY A
```

If B is neither similar to A (possible to partition by) or C (possible to aggregate) then I would keep the ROW_NUMBER() solution you included in the question.